# makefile "strip" function not working

Tags: bash, makefile

I want to define a variable in a makefile which should be a list of all the file dependencies in the project, separated by one space. I do this with:

```
DEP_LIST = $(shell g++ -M $(SRC_FILES) $(INC_DIRS))
```

which outputs all of my project dependencies, e.g:

```
main.o: src/main.cpp /usr/include/stdc-predef.h   /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream   /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/c++config.h ...
```

I filter out the `xxx.o:` bits with

```
DEP_LIST_FILTERED = $(filter-out %.o:, $(DEP_LIST))
```

which now outputs

```
src/main.cpp /usr/include/stdc-predef.h  /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream  /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/c++config.h ...
```

Looking good so far, now I just need to strip the double whitespace using:

```
DEP_LIST_STRIPPED = $(strip $(DEP_LIST_FILTERED))
```

However this has no effect and the output is the same as previous. Presumably this has something to do with how my shell (bash) treats whitespace, but I can't find any info about it. Any ideas?

EDIT: In case it's relevant, the reason I need to remove the double whitespace is that I want to pass the list to ctags in the form

```
ctags $(DEP_LIST_STRIPPED) -{options}
```

but in the current form it complains:

```
ctags: Warning: cannot open source file " /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream" : No such file or directory
```

Comment: Which version of [tag:make] are you using? `make --version`.  With GNU make 3.81 I see that `filter-out` removes the extra whitespace, without even the need for `strip`.

Comment: Heh, unfortunately if I try to pass the double whitespace version to ctags (which is what I want), it says `ctags: Warning: cannot open source file " /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream" : No such file or directory` :P

Comment: `$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81`

Comment: I don't think the problem is what you think.  Unless there's something extraordinarily bizarre about your shell, your system, or your version of make there's something else going on that you haven't shown us.  Please cut and paste the part of the makefile that invokes `ctags` into your question, and also cut and paste the output that make prints before that error (show us the `ctags` command line).  At this point my best guess is that character is not a real space: it's some i18n character that prints like a space, but is not an ASCII space, tab, or newline character.

Comment: @MadScientist From the gcc docs *"If there are many included files then the rule is split into several lines using ‘\’-newline"*

Comment: Yes, so, if the original poster had shown us the actual `ctags` command line that make invoked the problem would have been _immediately_ obvious because we would have seen the backslashes there.  Just sayin'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be what `g++` [generates with the `-M` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options):

> If there are many included files then the rule is split into several lines using ‘\’-newline

It appears as if `make`s `$(shell )` function removes the newlines, but the `\` characters stay in place, thus effectively escaping some of the extra whitespaces.  If you add a rule like this:

```
echo:
    echo "$(DEP_LIST_FILTERED)"
```

and then `make echo`, you should see a list, something like this:

> src.c /usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream \ /usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/./bits/c++config.h \ /usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/./bits/os_defines.h ...

So I think a possible fix here is simply to also filter-out the `\` strings:

```
DEP_LIST_FILTERED1 = $(filter-out \ , $(DEP_LIST_FILTERED))

echo1:
    echo "$(DEP_LIST_FILTERED1)"
```

Then `make echo1` displays I think what you want.

Comment: Whoops, you are absolutely right. The reason I didn't spot this: I was using simply `echo $(DEP_LIST_STRIPPED)` to print my output, without the quotation marks, which doesn't print the backspaces in bash. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnnyLyco Yep the shell and `make` both have their different quoting gotchas - you have to carefully consider both in makefile recipes.

Comment: Make will print the command that it's going to invoke (if you don't put a `@` before the command).  If you look at that, you'll see exactly what the shell sees.  If you try to print the command line yourself using the shell's `echo` or whatever, then you have to worry about the shell quoting etc.

Comment: @MadScientist `$(filter-out \ :, $(DEP_LIST_FILTERED))` feels a little ugly/hacky to me.  I will happily accept any recommendation for a cleaner fix than this.

Comment: No need for the colon btw, I was filtering a colon before. In the end the full procedure was `DEP_LIST1 = $(shell g++ -M $(SRC_FILES) $(INC_DIRS))`
`DEP_LIST2 = $(filter-out %.o:, $(DEP_LIST1))`
`DEP_LIST3 = $(filter-out \, $(DEP_LIST2))`
`DEP_LIST = $(strip $(DEP_LIST3))` - I'm sure it could be more concise but it works!